# Calculate percentage change between two columns using for loop

Tags: python, pandas

| Group | Subgroup | pre_product_A | post_product_A | *product_A_Change* | pre_product_B | post_product_B | *product_B_Change* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Group A | Sub A | 100 | 150 | ***50%*** | 100 | 150 | ***50%*** |
| Group A | Sub B | 50 | 70 | ***40%*** | 50 | 70 | ***40%*** |
| Group B | Sub A | 60 | 20 | ***-67%*** | 60 | 70 | ***-67%*** |
| Group B | Sub B | 40 | 10 | ***-75%*** | 40 | 10 | ***-75%*** |

I have a dataframe which shows the group, subgroup, pre and post figures for each product.

I want to calculate the percentage change for each product (as shown in columns 5 and 8). However I have up to 10 different products that I need to calculate this for. I'm trying to write a for loop in order to do this for me but not getting any luck.

```
def myfunc(a, b):
    return b/a-1
res = [myfunc(a, b) for a, b in zip(a, b)]

for a in [pre_product_A,pre_product_B]:
    for b in [post_product_A,post_product_B]:
    myfunc(a, b)

res
```

The only way I was able to get the result I wanted was by creating new columns individually but it is repetitive.

```
df['product_A'] = (df.post_product_A/df.pre_product_A -1).round(2)
df['product_B'] = (df.post_product_B/df.pre_product_B -1).round(2)

df.head()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try on that:

```
#First make a sample df 
import pandas as pd
data = [[15, 10, 10, 12], [12, 15, 2 , 6], [14, 10, 5, 10]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['post_product_A',
     'pre_product_A','post_product_B','pre_product_B'])

#Then Run
prodlist=['product_A','product_B']
for product in prodlist:
      df['Change_'+product]=(100* (df['post_'+product] / df['pre_'+product] -1)).map("{:,.0f}%".format)
df
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I wanted with a few minor adjustments. Since I already had a dataframe that I wanted to reference I just replaced the 'data' part with my actual dataframe. I also wanted to retain my first two columns 'Group' & 'Subgroup' so I added those two columns in my column list. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If all your columns are named the same: `pre_product_<product_name>` and `post_product_<product_name>`, then you can create new columns for each of them, in a loop like so:

```py
products = ["A", "B"]  # list all your product names here

for product in products:
    pre = df[f"pre_product_{product}"]
    post = df[f"post_product_{product}"]
    df[f"product_{product}"] = (post/pre -1).round(2)
```

Otherwise, you will have to "hardcode" the names of the columns:

```py
pre_columns = ["pre_product_A", "pre_product_B"]
post_columns = ["post_product_A", "post_product_B"]
end_columns = ["product_A_Change", "product_B_Change"]

for pre, post, end in zip(pre_columns, post_columns, end_columns):
    df[end] = (df[post]/df[pre] -1).round(2)
```

Comment: I tried the first solution and it gives me the result that I want but for some reason it only returns the results for the last product in my product list.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm not sure I understand

Comment: In my list I have product A, product B etc. all the way up to Product F for example. But when I run my script it only shows the results for Product F instead of all the products in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, but your request is not perfectly clear...
Are you using python lists or dataframes?
Have you got 10 different products or groups?
Here are 3 simple snippets that may help you, hoping to have understood what you really want to accomplish.

First solution:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Group': ['Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B'],
    'Subgroup': ['Sub A', 'Sub B', 'Sub A', 'Sub B'],
    'Pre-Product-1': [900, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-1': [150, 70, 20, 10],
    'Product-1-Change': ['50%', '50%', '-67%', '-75%'],
    'Pre-Product-2': [200, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-2': [150, 70, 10, 10],
    'Product-2-Change': ['50%', '50%', '-67%', '-75%']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def calc_pct_change(pre, post):
    return (post - pre) / pre * 100

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    '''Define a function to calculate percentage change + use the % notation'''
    for j in range(1, 3):
        pre_col = f'Pre-Product-{j}'
        post_col = f'Post-Product-{j}'
        change_col = f'Product-{j}-Change'
        pre = row[pre_col]
        post = row[post_col]
        change = calc_pct_change(pre, post)
        df.loc[i, change_col] = f'{change:.0f}%'

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
```

Second solution (with 0 or None values in the original df):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Group': ['Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B'],
    'Subgroup': ['Sub A', 'Sub B', 'Sub A', 'Sub B'],
    'Pre-Product-1': [100, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-1': [150, 70, 20, 10],
    'Product-1-Change': [0, 0, 0, 0],
    'Pre-Product-2': [100, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-2': [150, 70, 10, 10],
    'Product-2-Change': [0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

for i in range(1, 3):
    '''Loop over each product and assign percentage change to the "change_col" column and use % notation'''
    pre_col = f'Pre-Product-{i}'
    post_col = f'Post-Product-{i}'
    change_col = f'Product-{i}-Change'
    df[change_col] = (round(((df[post_col] - df[pre_col]) / df[pre_col] * 100), 2)).astype(str) + '%'

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
```

Third solution (with 0 or None values in the original df):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Group': ['Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B'],
    'Subgroup': ['Sub A', 'Sub B', 'Sub A', 'Sub B'],
    'Pre-Product-1': [100, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-1': [150, 70, 20, 10],
    'Product-1-Change': [None,None,None,None],
    'Pre-Product-2': [100, 50, 60, 40],
    'Post-Product-2': [150, 70, 10, 10],
    'Product-2-Change': [0,0,0,0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def calc_pct_change(pre, post):
    '''Define a function to calculate percentage change + use the % notation'''
    return [f"{(b-a)/a*100:.0f}%" for a, b in zip(pre, post)]

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    '''
    Loop over each row and calculate percentage change
    Get the product number from the pre column name
    Update the value in the existing 'Product-i-Change' column
    ''' 
    pre_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Pre')]
    post_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col.startswith('Post')]
    for pre_col, post_col in zip(pre_cols, post_cols):
        pre = row[pre_col]
        post = row[post_col]
        change = calc_pct_change([pre], [post])[0]
        product_num = pre_col.split('-')[2]
        product_change_col = f"Product-{product_num}-Change"
        df.loc[i, product_change_col] = change
        print("row", row)

pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing the structure of your dataframe, to make it more aligned with the underlying logic. Then it will be easy to calculate the values you need without a loop.

With your example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B'],
                   'Subgroup': ['Sub A', 'Sub B', 'Sub A', 'Sub B'],
                   'pre_product_A': [100, 50, 60, 40],
                   'post_product_A': [150, 70, 20, 10],
                   'pre_product_B': [100, 50, 60, 40],
                   'post_product_B': [150, 70, 70, 10]})

df.set_index(['Group', 'Subgroup'], inplace=True)

products = ['A', 'B']
phases = ['pre', 'post']

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([products, phases], 
                                        names=['product', 'phase'])
df = df.stack(level='product')

df['change'] = 100 * df.post // df.pre - 100

print(df)
```

```
phase                     post  pre  change
Group   Subgroup product                   
Group A Sub A    A         150  100      50
                 B         150  100      50
        Sub B    A          70   50      40
                 B          70   50      40
Group B Sub A    A          20   60     -67
                 B          70   60      16
        Sub B    A          10   40     -75
                 B          10   40     -75
```